# Homescreen toggle shortcut for color inversion under accessibility in Android 6.0

Tags: accessibility

Is there any way, shortcut or app which just toggles the color inversion option which is under Accessibility in Settings.

It is cumbersome to go to Settings ~ Additional settings ~ Accessibility ~ Color inversion.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Can you add to the drop menu in your Android version?]

LineageOS allows this but as Android features vary from device to device...